# Adaptive grid of <div>

Tags: html, css-tables, grid-layout

I want to make a webpage where there are, like, table 25-50 divs, and amount of divs in one row depends on html window size (e.g. 6 100px divs in a row for screen width of 640px, and 10 divs in a row for 1024px) How to implement it?

Comment: Pure HTML (maybe + CSS), if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this only with **CSS** using the `float` propety like this :

```
div{
    float:left;
}
```

See this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YS5d7/3/)** as an example.

Comment: Man, this looks like what I've been searching for! But Is it possible align it to middle? Could I use a parent div with align:middle?

Comment: Well, It's not really aligned to be in the middle.

Comment: @RomaValcer then you need to use the display:inline-block property see this fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/YS5d7/17/

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally unchecked your answer as correct, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
#wrap div{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    background:aqua;
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius: 10px;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-bottom:10px
}
```

Check the update fiddle code too: http://jsfiddle.net/YS5d7/26/